# What's the difference between Sphinx's "only" and "ifconfig" directives?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, conditional-compilation

Sphinx knows two directives for conditional content:

- only => https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#including-content-based-on-tags
- ifconfig => https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/ifconfig.html

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## `only`

The `only` directive is used to include/exclude content based on `tags`. `tags` can be specified:

1. In the conf.py (this use makes `only` pretty similar to `ifconfig`)
2. Using the `-t` flag to `sphinx-build` (doesn't work as a flag to `make` because `-t` is the `--touch` flag for `make`)

   example.rst

   ```
   .. only:: draft

      This message only appears in drafts.
   ```

   command

   ```
   $ sphinx-build  -t draft  -b html -d _build/doctrees . _build/html
   ```
3. The format or name of builder. **This is where `only` shines**. `.. only:: html` contents would only get built when you use `make html` etc.

   example.rst

   ```
   .. only:: html

      This message only appears in HTML output.
   ```

   command

   ```
   $ make html
   ```

## `ifconfig`

`ifconfig` gives you the flexibility to include content based on the true-ness of any Python expression involving configuration variables registered in conf.py. This means, though, that you have to edit the conf.py to change whether content is included or excluded.

## Conclusion

If you want your content to change without editing conf.py you want `only`.
For example, I use `only` to include a table of contents (`contents` directive) in my HTML docs, but not in my pdf docs (because LaTeX produces those on its own).