# Sphinx: Hide `{contents}` in LaTeX build

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, myst

index.rst

```
======================================
MyTitle
======================================
.. raw:: latex

   \section*{MyTitle}

Some text

.. toctree::
      :hidden:
      :titlesonly:
      :caption: Setup

   setup_macos
```

setup_macos.md

````
```{contents} On this page:
```

# macOS setup

In this tutorial...
````

The question is about the `{contents}` tag in setup_macos.md.

This causes a "local" TOC to be generated. This is desirable in the HTML docs, but I do not want it in the latexpdf docs.

How can I put a local TOC in HTML pages, but hide it from LaTeX output?

Comment: https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/roles-and-directives.html shows that this syntax just gets translated(?) into RST, where the command does work. In any event, yes, this code block is ignored in latex, so it seems to be working (sort of) as intended. `if-builder` is documented [here](https://sphinx-simplepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689206/whats-the-difference-between-sphinxs-only-and-ifconfig-directives

Comment: Which extension? I'm trying to use latexpdf, *not* simplepdf.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. The question still stands: what's the right way to get a local TOC in HTML but not in LaTeX. Feel free to use whatever approach you want :) As I pointed out, if-builder isn't really doing the right thing for me anyway.

Comment: Looks like the same behavior: PDF looks fine, HTML has the literal string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the `contents` directive in an [`only`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-only) directive. Use backticks as described here: https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/roles-and-directives.html#nesting-directives.

`````
````{only} html
```{contents} On this page:
```
````
`````

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. It also works with `{if-builder}` instead of `{only}`, for what it's worth. The trick I was missing is that you used four ticks for the outer command, and three ticks for the inner command. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: See the documentation of "Nesting directives" that I linked to.